# Ler linhas de um arquivo Txt e jogar em diferentes Edits

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Possuo a seguinte estrutura de `.Txt`:

```
--------DEF--------
3
25
3
2
46
------PROF1----------
0-20 cm
100%
100%
100%
10%
33%
0%
100%
0%
Outro
```

Gostaria de Que quando o usuário escolhesse a opção do `.Txt` no `comboBox`, que fosse igual o nome do arquivo ele jogasse o valor de cada linha em um edit diferente algo assim:

```
Edit1.text = linha 2
edit2.text = linha 3 
...
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Pode explicar melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente:

```
procedure TForm1.btnProcessarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   stlArquivo: TStringList;
begin
   stlArquivo := nil;
   try
      stlArquivo := TStringList.Create;
      stlArquivo.LoadFromFile('seuarquivo.txt');
      edtNome.Text := stlArquivo[1];
      edtSobrenome.Text := stlArquivo[2];
   finally
      if Assigned(stlArquivo) then FreeAndNil(stlArquivo);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: perfeito, Obrigado.

Comment: se fosse um arquivo .ini seria fácil.